# Why constraint cannot be added?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a graph tables and want to add constraint. Do as in the MS doc here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/graph-edge-constraints?view=sql-server-2017

I do it:

```
ALTER TABLE bought ADD CONSTRAINT EC_BOUGHT1 CONNECTION (Customer TO Product, Supplier TO Product);
```

But receive the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near 'CONNECTION'.

What is the reason? how to fix it?

Comment: Oddly the syntax is in the documentation way back in [2018](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/27db605f31e32c780516723be3a8082e859c873d), but the syntax *does not* work on a [2017 instance](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yd19Cckd). It works fine on [2019+](https://dbfiddle.uk/9OO7hhfZ) though.

Comment: @Larnu I have got this example from the SQL 2017 documentation (the link is added). I know about SQL 2019, but I need SQL 2017 . What is the correct syntax?

Comment: This is a SQL Server 2019 feature https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/public-preview-of-graph-edge-constraints-on-sql-server-2019/ba-p/386004

Comment: Ok, can yo please check the link in my start post?

Comment: the documentation is wrong.

Comment: See also https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5744/overview-of-sql-server-2019-features/

Comment: SO if you're using 2017, you cannot create the constraints

Comment: Ok, but I have read the MS doc and trusted it ;-)

Comment: @ZedZip, I suspect edge constraints were in SQL 2017 CTP 2.0 but didn't make the RTM version and the doc wasn't revised to remove it.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman , now more clear, will change my scripts

Comment: @DanGuzman - they were part of the preview for 2019 not 2017 - per the "announcement" link I posted above. Just looks like whoever created the docs messed up the "applies to"

Comment: public preview of SQL Server 2019 was announced at start of the 2018 Ignite conference (Sep 2018)  - Announcement post was [Sep 28, 2018](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/public-preview-of-graph-edge-constraints-on-sql-server-2019/ba-p/386004)  - docs created in Sep 2018 https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/27db605f31e32c780516723be3a8082e859c873d

Comment: @MartinSmith, I agree the doc is wrong/misleading.  Edge constraints are listed under [Graph features introduced in SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#graph-features-introduced-in-). The What's New in SQL 2017 page links to that page and references CTP 2.0, which is why I thought it may have been in a pre-RTM version.

Comment: The docs look like they are going to be a bit of a mess to clear up then!

Comment: @BogdanSahlean aasjdkfk sdjkhf yes? Notice the fiddle is for SQL Server 2017...

Comment: I've asked microsoft to update the docs here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/8544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect edge constraints were included in SQL Server 2017 CTP 2.0 but the feature didn't make the RTM version. I don't have an old SQL Server CTP install to verify my theory but edge constraints are not available in SQL Server 2017 RTM, at least through the latest CU (CU31 as of this writing).

Per the comments, @siggemannen submitted [doc feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/8544) to have the documentation clarified. Edge constraints are available in SQL Server 2019 and later versions, including Azure SQL Database.